# ElasticSearch wildcard highlighting with hyphen

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having trouble with wildcard query. When i have some hyphen - it does not highlight anything after it. I played with highlight settings but did not found any solution yet. Is it normal behavior?

I am making some index:

```json
PUT testhighlight

PUT testhighlight/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "text",
      "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
    }
  }
}
```

Then i create documents:

```json
PUT testhighlight/_doc/1
{
  "title": "1",
  "content": "test-input"
}


PUT testhighlight/_doc/2
{
  "title": "2",
  "content": "test input"
}

PUT testhighlight/_doc/3
{
  "title": "3",
  "content": "testinput"
}
```

Then i execute this search request:

```json
GET testhighlight/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ],
            "query": "test*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "boundary_max_scan": 10,
        "fragment_offset": 5,
        "fragment_size": 250,
        "type": "fvh",
        "number_of_fragments": 5,
        "order": "score",
        "boundary_scanner": "word",
        "post_tags": [
          "</span>"
        ],
        "pre_tags": [
          """<span class="highlight-search">"""
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns these hits:

```json
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "testhighlight",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "2",
      "content": "test input"
    },
    "highlight": {
      "content": [
        """<span class="highlight-search">test</span> input"""
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "testhighlight",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "1",
      "content": "test-input"
    },
    "highlight": {
      "content": [
        """<span class="highlight-search">test</span>-input"""
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "testhighlight",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "3",
      "content": "testinput"
    },
    "highlight": {
      "content": [
        """<span class="highlight-search">testinput</span>"""
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

It looks alright, but didn't highlighted the whole "test-input" in document with ID 1. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Try different types of highlighters, perhaps? It defaults to "unified", but there's also "plain" & "fvh". That's "type" property of "highlight" in your query.

Comment: I tried types. I also tried empty boundary chars with chars boundary scanner.